# How to make ajax auto-complete compulsory?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to force the user to select from the auto-complete options.

NB: I do not want to use a drop down menu.

Comment: means you don't wanna Autocomplete Dropdowns with the Datalist Element. likes http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
var isItemSelected = false;

 //Handler for AutoCompleter OnClientItemSelected event
  function onItemSelected() {
      isItemSelected = true;
  }

  //Handler for textbox blur event
  function checkItemSelected(myTextBox) {
      if (!isItemSelected) {
          alert("Please select item from the list only!");
          myTextBox.focus();
      }
      else {
          //reset isItemSelected
          isItemSelected = false;
      }
  }
```

And then throw this in the Textbox:

```
onblur="checkItemSelected(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i have this forum for the references .

[Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1774554.aspx?autocomplete%20extender%20force%20the%20user%20to%20only%20be%20able%20to%20select%20from%20the%20list%20returned),

You'll need to use the select and focus options to support this.
  **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZeHr/4/)**  example

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#tags" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
```